# Reviewing and correcting code style

Tags: java, android

I am new to android developement.
Created calculator application.
Want to improve my code quality.
Will be helpfull for any advice to make the code better and more professional
(overall structure, splitting onto logical units, accordance to code conventions, methods and variables names, comments etc).
Here is my code:

```
public class OperationsAndFunctions {

    static enum OperEnum {
        SUM, SUBSTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE, EQUAL
    }

    static enum FuncEnum {
        RESET, BACKSPACE, SIGN, PERCENT, POINT
    }
}

public class LCalculator extends Activity {

    private TextView mDisplay;
    private boolean mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
    private boolean mFirstNumberReceived;
    private boolean mNumberEntered;
    private boolean mPointEntered;

    private double sNum1;
    private double sNum2;

    private static OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum sOperation;
    private static OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum sFunction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        mDisplay.setText("0");
    }

    // listening for number buttons pressing
    public void num_Clicked(View view) {

        Button button = (Button) view;
        int number = 0;

        // checking button ID
        switch (button.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            number = 1;
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            number = 2;
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            number = 3;
            break;

        case R.id.button4:
            number = 4;
            break;

        case R.id.button5:
            number = 5;
            break;

        case R.id.button6:
            number = 6;
            break;

        case R.id.button7:
            number = 7;
            break;

        case R.id.button8:
            number = 8;
            break;

        case R.id.button9:
            number = 9;
            break;

        case R.id.button0:
            if (mDisplay.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                return;
            }
            number = 0;
            break;
        }

        // setting a new digit onto display if it is empty
        if (mDisplayIsEmpty) {

            if (!(number == 0)) {
                mDisplayIsEmpty = false;
            }
            mDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(number));
        }

        // appending digit if display isn't empty
        else {
            mDisplay.append(Integer.toString(number));
        }
        mNumberEntered = true;
    }

    // listenning for operational buttons pressing
    public void op_Clicked(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;

        // calculating and printing result
        // if a number has been entered before
        // (Not entering here if another operation has been pressed before)
        if (mNumberEntered) {
            // if received first number and saved to sNum1
            if (mFirstNumberReceived) {
                sNum2 = Double.parseDouble(mDisplay.getText().toString());
                printResult(calculateResult(sNum1, sOperation, sNum2));
                sNum1 = Double.parseDouble(mDisplay.getText().toString());
            }

            // if not received first number - receiving it now
            else {
                sNum1 = Double.parseDouble(mDisplay.getText().toString());
                mFirstNumberReceived = true;
            }
            mNumberEntered = false;
        }

        // checking operational buttons id
        // and assigning appropriate operations enum value
        switch (button.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonPlus:
            sOperation = OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum.SUM;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonMinus:
            sOperation = OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum.SUBSTRACT;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonMultiply:
            sOperation = OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum.MULTIPLY;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonDivide:
            sOperation = OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum.DIVIDE;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonEqual:
            sOperation = OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum.EQUAL;
            break;
        }

        // next digit entered will be a new number
        mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
        mPointEntered = false;
    }

    // listening for functional buttons pressing
    public void func_Clicked(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;

        // checking operational buttons id
        // and assigning appropriate functions enum value
        switch (button.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonAc:
            sFunction = OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum.RESET;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonC:
            sFunction = OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum.BACKSPACE;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonSign:
            sFunction = OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum.SIGN;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonPercent:
            sFunction = OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum.PERCENT;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonPoint:
            sFunction = OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum.POINT;
            break;
        }

        // implementing chosen function
        implementFunction(sFunction);
    }

    // implementing function
    private void implementFunction(OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum function) {
        sFunction = function;

        switch (function) {

        case RESET:
            reset();
            break;

        case BACKSPACE:
            printResult(Double.parseDouble(backSpace(mDisplay.getText())
                    .toString()));
            break;

        case SIGN:
            printResult(readDisplayState() * (-1));
            break;

        case PERCENT:
            printResult(readDisplayState() / 100);
            break;

        case POINT:
            if (!mPointEntered) {
                if (!mDisplayIsEmpty) {
                    mDisplay.append(".");
                } else {
                    mDisplay.setText("0.");
                    mDisplayIsEmpty = false;
                }
                mPointEntered = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // reseting the calculator
    private void reset() {
        mDisplay.setText("0");
        sNum1 = sNum2 = 0;
        mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
        mFirstNumberReceived = false;
        mNumberEntered = false;
        mPointEntered = false;
    }

    // deleting the last symbol on display
    private CharSequence backSpace(CharSequence displayState) {
        CharSequence result = displayState;

        if (displayState.length() > 1) {
            result = displayState.subSequence(0, displayState.length() - 1);
        }

        else if (displayState.length() == 1) {
            result = "0";
        }

        return result;
    }

    // calculating the result
    private double calculateResult(double num1,
            OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum operation, double num2) {

        sNum1 = num1;
        sNum2 = num2;
        sOperation = operation;
        double result = 0;

        switch (operation) {
        case SUM:
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;

        case SUBSTRACT:
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;

        case MULTIPLY:
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;

        case EQUAL:
            mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
            mNumberEntered = false;
            mFirstNumberReceived = false;
            break;

        case DIVIDE:
            // division by zero
            if (num2 == 0) {
                showError();
                break;
            }

            result = num1 / num2;
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // reading current displayNumber
    private double readDisplayState() {
        return Double.parseDouble(mDisplay.getText().toString());
    }

    // printing the result
    private void printResult(Double result) {
        // checking if the result having decimal part
        // if not then we print integer value of it without point and zero(s)
        if (result % 1 == 0) {
            mDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(result.intValue()));
        }

        else {
            mDisplay.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }
    }

    // Error message (in case of division by zero)
    private void showError() {
        // printing error message
        mDisplay.setText("Error");
        // and reseting current state
        sNum1 = sNum2 = 0;
        mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
        mFirstNumberReceived = false;
        mNumberEntered = false;
        mPointEntered = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is mainly for problems with your code. Please see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about it. Will post code there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code style can be either a personal preference, or an organizational guideline.  If working for yourself, do what works best for you.  Start with some published standard code guidelines ([Android Style Guide](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)) and then change things that you don’t like.  If you are working within a group, be it an open source project or as part of a project with an employer, there are typically coding standards set forth by them.  One bit of advice is even if you are not a fan of the chosen style, abide by it. Having an entire file show as updated just because you reformatted the style to match your preferences is not received well in a team environment.  As far as code quality, there are tools (Static analysis) that you can run against your code to give you suggestions of what might be places that could cause problems. ([Android Static Analysis](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html))